# implicitlyWait and appWaitActivity not working in uiautomator2

Tags: java, android, automation, appium, android-uiautomator

Before i do addition in capabilities ("automationame", "uiautomator2"), my code works well. But, after im using uiautomator2, the implicitlyWait is not working. The code doesn't wait for the element appears. If the elements doesn't exists, the automation going to shutdown soon. It also happened while move from one activity to another activity. Can anyone helps me to solve this issue?

Below is my setup code :

```
public void setUp() {
      System.out.println("Creating session.....");
      String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
      DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
      cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
      cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
      cap.setCapability("deviceName", "88929a3d");
      cap.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");
      cap.setCapability("appPackage", "io.selendroid.testapp");
      cap.setCapability("appActivity", "HomeScreenActivity");
      cap.setCapability("appWaitActivity", "HomeScreenActivity, RegisterUserActivity");
      cap.setCapability("appWaitDuration", 3000);
      cap.setCapability("app", path + "//apk//selendroid.apk");
      try {
          driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      System.out.println("Session is created successfully");
  }
```

Comment: What happens if you set "Appium" insteadof  "uiautomator2" ?

Comment: You don't need to set that capability at all.  You should, however, consider changing your driver declaration to `AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>` and use `AndroidElement` objects instead of `WebElement` objects in your code.

Comment: @pankajmishra it will back to uiautomator and not used uiautomator2 anymore

Comment: @BillHileman I already tried that and it won't affect anything. I still able to locate all the element. It doesn't impact to my case

Answer (score 0):

**ImplicitWait** is not a solution for element waiting. It is a way to set **timeout for pulling DOM when trying to find an element(s)** if it is not immediately available.

Use **explicit wait** to wait for element:

```html
new WebDriverWait(driver,<timeoutInSeconds>)
             .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(<locator>));
```

Note: 
In your code you set **appWaitDuration** [capability](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md)

> Timeout in milliseconds used to wait for the appWaitActivity to launch
>   (default 20000)

it has nothing to do with elements and 3 sec is not enough in my opinion

Comment: But my question is, if i'm using uiautomator instead uiautomator2, the implicitlyWait is working as well. Appium will wait the element as long as the timeout and continue soon after the element appear.

Comment: I'm using UiAutomator2 and imlicit waiting works perfectly. To get your case post Appium server logs, server version and java client version

Comment: im using appium version 1.8.1 and Java 1.8.1

Comment: add code snippet and appium server logs to help with understanding your issue